# Why pickup service needs wake up from Postfix master?

Tags: postfix, email-server

The Postfix master.cf file contains a definition to wake up qmgr service:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
...
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
...
```

From qmgr [man page](https://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html), "awaits the arrival of incoming mail and arranges for its delivery via Postfix delivery processes." that's true, I see how the mails are moving along incoming and active queues as soon as they arrive.

But why is it needed a wake up time? the qmgr process is up an running all the time, doing their work. When the wake up schedule, I spect to see work only after their call, every 300s, but it doesn't make too much sense, because in that case, only the mails are being moved every that time.

Comment: The man you linked says that 'the wakeup call ... The action is to  start an incoming queue scan'

Answer (score 0):

After enabling verbose "qmgr -v" the log print more insights, the process seems to wake up at the schedule time defined on master.cf:

```
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068813+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: trigger_server_accept_local: trigger arrived
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068835+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: master_notify: status 0
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068841+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: request: 87 (W)
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068848+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: request: 0 (?)
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068854+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: request ignored
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068861+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: qmgr_scan_start: start incoming queue scan
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068867+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: master_notify: status 1
2024-01-22T11:53:09.068874+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: done incoming queue scan
```

And when a new mail arrives, the qmgr spin up and inserts the named message file into the active queue.

```
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274607+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: trigger_server_accept_local: trigger arrived
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274630+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: master_notify: status 0
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274640+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: request: 87 (W)
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274649+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: request: 0 (?)
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274658+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: request ignored
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274667+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: qmgr_scan_start: start incoming queue scan
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274676+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: master_notify: status 1
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274685+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: qmgr_active_feed: queue incoming
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274695+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: qmgr_active_feed: incoming/419B440602
2024-01-22T11:59:44.274704+01:00 mx postfix/qmgr[3633521]: qmgr_message_alloc: active 419B440602
```

So i can confirm the idea proposed on the [postfix mail list](https://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-users@postfix.org/msg30521.html)

> I don't believe that qmgr would run at all, except when a connection
> comes in on port 25. I haven't looked at the postfix source code, but
> it seems like postfix is smart enough to check for qmgr when a
> connection comes in, sees that it isn't running, and spawns it.
> Likewise, every 5 minutes it's trying to wake up qmgr, seeing that
> it's not running, and spawning it.

The qmgr doesn't need to wait until wake up time, when a new mail arrives, cleanup service calls it, and also when the master process has configured.